# Hi,my html snippets in vs code does not work

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am recently using sublime text editor and now shifted to vs code by hearing all the positve reviews for vs code but I am continously facing various issues one major issue is that when ever I try to use a tag for eg: 'input' tag some snippets are available in the dropdown menu but when I click those nothing happens,I tried to install and uninstall various packages but nothing was working,some other editors i have used,will auto provide input,id field in input tag.[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgAmI.png)
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Luo.png)

[image: it automatically completes the tag by adding id and name attribute3]

Comment: you are not using snippets, you just use the close tag feature of VSC

Answer (score 0):

Vs code HTML snippets tag auto snippets code block based on the package you installed. make sure the file with the relevant file type extension checks the package description file type supported.

after adding any package not work restart the vs code.

see this screenshot HTML snippet working on vs code

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I think I did not convey the problem, the problem persists even after closing and refreshing the page, I have installed HTML snippets but no change, whenever I try to open an HTML tag it shows the options below but clicking those does nothing, the tag is not closing itself even after I installed auto close tag. any other suggestions plz, also I am a very noob to programming so it would be nice if you could explain it in such a way that it is easy to understand

Comment: I also wanted to know is this really a problem I am facing or vs code does not have this feature at all,

Comment: @MNARESH screenshot 1 is for HTML snippets, screenshot 2 is using Emmet, 2 very different things

Comment: @rioV8 what package in vsc should i install to get these emet abbrevation for html tags

Comment: @MNARESH they are part of VSC by default, read the doc page about Emmet

Comment: @rioV8 I think would be a good idea, i will surely go for it and will update if i resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found that the problem is with my vs code extension settings, as you can see below.
to solve this issue remove the statement emmet. exclude languages completely and change the value of "emmet.triggerExapansionOnTab" to true also one more final step, include the statement-->
"files.associations": {"html": "html"}, in the file,
thank you everyone for the comments and suggestions.

[image: I have marked the wrong statements]